# Count common ManyToMany members in queryset

Tags: python, django, orm, relational-database, django-queryset

Assuming I have such models:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    pass # some simple Model goes here

class Foo(models.Model):
    bars = models.ManyToManyField(Bar)
```

And some variable `main_object = Foo()` with `bars` filled, how can I make a Queryset so that it's annotated with the number of common `bars` elements betweeen each entity and `main_object`?

Example:

There are three `Bar` records, with primary keys 1, 2 and 3. `main_object` has pk=2 as member set in `bars`.

`Foo` has two records: `main_object` and another with pk=1 set in `bars`. In this case, I want an annotation that has the value of 0, since said record has no common `Bar` foreign keys with `main_object`.

I can imagine something similar to `Foo.objects.filter(bars__in=<some_values_here>)` but instead of simply checking presence, actually counting it like `from django.db.models.Count`.

Is it even solvable via Querysets or I should resort to manual counting through loops?

In practical use, such way of querying can be useful in similarity ranking, but it seems non-trivial for me.

Comment: I am not sure, but `Foo.objects.filter(bars__in=main_objects.bars.all())` may be the thing you want

Comment: @sudden_appearance you may be right, I was considering it but couldn't find a source if such annotation would be more "inclusive" than should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

Foo.objects.annotate(
    common_count=Count(
        'bars',
        filter=Q(bars__foo=main_object)
    )
)
```

or if you only want to retrieve objects that have at least one `Bar` in common:

```
Foo.objects.filter(
    bars__foo=main_object
).distinct()
```